# How is css ID selector select two element with same id?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was reading about the difference between `ID` and `class` selectors where it says

**"Each page can have only one element with that ID"**

Though, How the `#one` managed to select both HTML elements.

```css
#one {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="one"> blue</p>
  <h1 id="one"> H1</h1>
</div>
```

Result run on chrome browser: both elements are displayed with blue color .

Comment: It's invalid HTML regardless

Comment: From [the spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#id-selectors): _“An ID selector represents an element instance that has an identifier that matches the identifier in the ID selector. (It is possible in non-conforming documents for multiple elements to match a single ID selector.)”_.

Comment: you need to change `id` to `class` to be a valid HTML.

Comment: CSS will still apply styling to elements with the same `id`, however, as j08691 pointed out, it's invalid HTML.

Comment: @Gildas.Tambo That’s not the question.

Comment: @SebastianSimon is it mentioning a specific scenarios where it will be working ?

Comment: @disinfor The question is not asking whether duplicate IDs are valid. The question is asking why CSS applies styles to an invalid document.

Comment: @SebastianSimon yeah, I read the question. Look at my response. CSS will be applied regardless if the HTML is invalid - because CSS doesn't care about HTML validity..it's simply searching for matching selectors.

Comment: I think also the css style will be cheaper/easier to render without checking if the html is valid ;)

Answer (score -3):

In HTML, each id has to be unique, while various elements can have the same class.

CSS that starts with a tag apply to all the tags in your HTML code.  p {color: red;} means all paragraphs will be red.

CSS that starts with the id tag apply to all the ids. #one {color: red;} means both lines will be red.

CSS that starts with the class tag apply to all elements of a class.  .test {color: red;} means only elements with the class 'test' will be red. Example:

```
<div>
  <p id="one" class='test1'> blue</p>
  <h1 id="two" class='test2'> H1</h1>
</div>
```

And your css looks like:

```
.test1 {color: blue;}
.test2 {color: green;}
```

Blue will be blue, and H1 will be green.

Comment: OP asks "why" it works, despite invalid syntax, and your answer doesn't explain that.